# Searching through really big files

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, data-recovery

I need to search through a TB of raw hard disk data. I need to find a couple of things inside. I tried using `sudo cat /dev/sdc | less` but this fails because it puts everything into RAM that is read. I only have 8 GB of RAM and 8 in swap space so putting a whole TB of data into RAM will not work.

I was wondering if I could somehow make `less` forgot what it has read after the 1GB mark or maybe use another editor.

I accidentally repartitioned my drive and lost some important files. I tried some utilities but none of them worked so I tried this. I got a few of the files but I can't get the rest because the computer freezes and runs out of RAM.

I learned my lesson, I need to make more frequent backups. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-B` option to `less` is exactly what you ask for. It allows `less` to be forgetful. Combine with `-b1048576` to allocate 1G (the `-b` unit is K)

Or do it the interactive way: run `less` normally, scroll down until the point where it starts to get a little laggy, then just type `-B` at the less prompt to activate the option (did you know you can set `less` options interactively?)

Just don't try to scroll backward very far or you'll be forgotten-content land, where weird things happen.

(Side note: I've done this kind of recovery before, and it's easier if you can find the filesystem structures (inode blocks etc.) that point to the data, rather than searching for the data in a big dump. Even if some of the inodes are gone, by first recovering everything you can from the surviving inodes you narrow down the range of unknown blocks where the other files might be.)

Comment: I couldn't use the whole -b1048576, I had to use something more like -b1000, Not sure why. Any links you know of to help me find file system structures and use them? I think it used to be NTFS, now there is a Linux image overwriting a little bit of the beginning of the drive.